# Bash select line and execute command

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script called x, I also have a text file. how do i create a bash script to execute the command based on the line? for example:
script name x
text name test

i want the bash script to select each line and do:

> python x.py $line >>log.txt

then go to the next line and do

> python x.py $line2 >>log.txt

an so on

Comment: This should help: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=textFileName
while read -r line
do
python x.py $line >>log.txt
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: thank you very much. this works. how about adding sleep time between executions ?